# 64-bit mongodb multiple-shards Issue

Tags: mongodb

I am using 64-bit MongoDB, and i am undergoing test on multiple-shards. If i keep multiple shards in a single machine. Its working fine but if i keep shards in different machine, its failed in sharding to second shard. I have restricted the first-shard size to 10MB, once its reaches the limited size in first shard it should start sharding to second-shard but not happening so.Instead failed to store in second-shard updating to first shard.  The following are my shard details. In my environment initially i have two shards. The first shard is on my first-machine running along with my application. The Second-shard is on my second machine. 
Configuration as follows:-
*)On both of my shards, shard-server,configserver,mongos and i have connected mongo through mongos as follows ./mongo hostname:27017/admin and i have added both the shards in  first & second shard and enabled sharding for database and collection level by using shard-key.
Please, let me know if i gone wrong anywhere in the configuration.

Advance Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post could use some editing, this is very difficult to read.

It looks like you have 2 machines. On each machine you have:

- `mongod` process serving as one shard
- `mongod` process serving as a config
- `mongos` process
- a copy of your application connecting to `localhost:27017/admin`

> Please, let me know if i gone wrong anywhere in the configuration.

There are several possible problems here. Please check the following:

1. You can only have 1 or 3 config processes. It looks like you have 2, this will not work.
2. When you connect to `localhost:27017/admin` are you connecting to `mongos` or `mongod`? Either one could be running on those ports. Can you specify the ports for each process to help clarify? You **must** connect to `mongos` or the sharding will not happen.
3. Please look at the logs, they generally have output indicating what the server is doing. If there is no indication of "splits" or "chunks" happening, then your database may be configured incorrectly.

Your best bet is to start from top and test each piece one at a time.

Comment: Hi @Gates VP,Thanks for your precious information.I am regret for my post have some complication to read.

Comment: The following are my port details:- sharserver-->10001,configserver-->20001,mongos-->Connected to configserver port:20001. Mongos running on the default port:27017[Port not Specified]. These are the port details which i am using on each three machines.Please let me know if i used wrong one. Once again thanks for your help.